# How to upload an image from an external link to google cloud storage?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, image-uploading

I am using `google-cloud-storage` on Node.js . Trying to find a solution to programmatically download an image from an external url then upload to GCS.

I'm using fetch API to get the image and turn it into a blob

```
fetch('image.jpg').then( res => {
    var blob = res.blob()
})
```

All tutorials I've found on the web deal with form upload using multer. But nothing about my case.

Now what's the right solution to upload this blob on my GCS bucket ?

**EDIT** : I've also tried this, without success

```
bucket.upload(urlImage, function(err, file){
            const blobStream = file.createWriteStream();
            blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
              console.log('error',err)
            });

            blobStream.on('finish', () => {
              console.log('finished with success')

              });

              blobStream.end(file);
          })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the request module for Node.js to obtain the image from the URL and pipe the result to be written into the bucket:

```
var request = require('request');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('your-bucket-name');
const file = bucket.file('image-name.jpg'); 

request(‘image-URL’).pipe(file.createWriteStream());
```

It worked for me.